# When is the kernel-mode TTY emulation (Linux console) used instead of user-mode TTY emulation (PTY)?

Tags: linux, shell, tty

Having read [this](https://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php) canonical article on TTYs, I'm not sure when kernel-mode TTY emulation (Linux console) is used instead of user-mode TTY emulation (e.g. `xterm`).

Normally, I'm always using `gnome-terminal`, `xterm`, or some other user-mode TTY emulation, so how does kernel-mode TTY emulation fit into this picture? Is Linux console the first TTY that is started, which allows the user to subsequently run e.g. `xterm`?

Kernel-mode terminal emulation:
[image]

User-mode terminal emulation (PTY):

[image]

Comment: The kernel mode tty emulation (virtual tty) is only used for the "black" terminals (either vga or frame buffer) that you can access with ctrl-alt-f1, ctrl-alt-f2, etc. They don't even exist on many platforms (neither my router nor my phone has anything like that). Neither pseudo-ttys (as used by xterm, gnome-terminal, ssh, etc) nor actual serial ttys have anything to do with them.

Comment: Thanks @mosvy - if these kernel-mode ttys (`/dev/tty*`) aren't used for anything useful, why do they still exist today?

Comment: They are useful. They allow you to use linux on a PC-like machine with keyboard and screen without having to install any extra software or use another machine from which to connect via a serial link or network connection.

Comment: Userspace terminal emulator don't rely on /dev/ttyX functionality, but pty functionality.

Comment: @mosvy - aren't all terminals (tty or pty-based) associated to vga? They are all rendered on the monitor. Or what do you mean by "either vga or frame buffer"?

Comment: No, they aren't. This is not metaphysics where everything is somehow "associated to vga". "vga" is the classic, fast, dos-style 80x25 text mode (where the characters are rendered in hardware), and "frame buffer" is the current slow, tiny ugly font tty excuse whose only purpose is to be a fallback for when X11/Wayland doesn't work.

Comment: @mosvy - thank you. I'd accept your answer in comments, if I could, since it is very comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

Kernel-mode TTY emulation is the `/dev/tty*` devices that don't involve any X/Wayland programs at all. You use them by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 or similar. User-mode TTY emulation is basically anything else that gives you a terminal, and are the `/dev/pts/*` devices. They're what's created by gnome-terminal, sshd, screen, and basically everything else.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any reason why all terminal emulation is not moved into userland (PTYs)?

Comment: @mosvy mentions that kernel-mode tty emulation is only used for "black" terminals that don't exist on many platforms. Why do we see them in `/dev/tty*` then?

Comment: @Shuzheng there are no `/dev/ttyN` devices on my router or phone (both running Linux).

Comment: @Shuzheng you may be interested in reading https://www.mail-archive.com/dri-devel@lists.freedesktop.org/msg156108.html